# Why am I getting "Failed to get account name from gcloud. Please authorize and re-try installation." with asmcli with service account?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-anthos, google-anthos-service-mesh

I am trying to run...

```
asmcli validate --project_id <proj> --cluster_name <cluster --cluster_location us-central1 --fleet_id <fleet> --output_dir ./out
```

But when I do I get...

```
asmcli: Setting up necessary files...
asmcli: Using /.../.../asm_kubeconfig as the kubeconfig...
asmcli: Checking installation tool dependencies...
asmcli: Fetching/writing GCP credentials to kubeconfig file...
asmcli: [WARNING]: nc not found, skipping k8s connection verification
asmcli: [WARNING]: (Installation will continue normally.)
asmcli: Getting account information...
asmcli: [ERROR]: Failed to get account name from gcloud. Please authorize and re-try installation.
```

Why am I getting this error message. How do I get it to allow me to deploy anthos with the service account. Auth happens via...

`ENV CLOUDSDK_AUTH_CREDENTIAL_FILE_OVERRIDE=/sa-key.json`

Answer (score 1):

I needed to actually authenticate using the following command...

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account <service-account-email> --key-file=/sa-key.json
```